# Active record query wrong result on Heroku

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, heroku

## Situation

#### Overview

I have a project which iOS app sends post request with multi tag( string ) parameters.
**Tags** are written **in Japanese**.

Request is sent to ruby on rails project and it return articles matches sent tags(  and query ).

On rails project articles and tags have has_and_belong_to_many relation.

#### DB

- Development: SQLite
- Production : PostgreSQL

## Problem

The rails project returns correct result when run on local server( by rails server command) but It doesn’t work correctly when deployed to Heroku.

Ex. 
TagA and TagB are sent as param.

The result articles should contain both TabA and TagB but some of returned articles only contain TagB.

It seems it works properly on some tags.

How do I make this work properly?

### Client Code (Swift)

```
static func serverWhere( tags: [String] , completion: (articles: [FeedArticle]) -> () ) {

        Alamofire.request(.POST, Constants.domain + "/amsarticles/tags", parameters: ["tags": tags ], headers: Constants().authHeader() )
            .responseJSON { response in

                switch response.result {
                case .Success:
                    if let value = response.result.value {
                        print(response.response?.statusCode)
                        let json = JSON(value)

                        var articles: [FeedArticle] = []
                        for articleJson in json.arrayValue {
                            if let article = deserialize(articleJson) {
                                articles.append(article)
                            }
                        }


                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                            completion(articles: articles )
                        })
                    }

                case .Failure(let error):
                    print(response.response?.statusCode)
                    print(error)
                    completion(articles: [])
                }
            }
    }
```

### Server code (ruby)

```
def tags

  limit = 300
  required_tags = params[:tags] 

  articles = Amsarticle.joins(:tags).order("id DESC").limit( limit )
     .where(tags: { name: required_tags })
     .group('amsarticles.id')
     .having('count(*) = ?', required_tags.count)

  distributable_articles = articles.where("distribute = ?", true ) 

  render status: 200, json: distributable_tag_relation_merged_articles_json( distributable_articles )

end
```

Comment: Can you post the SQL that is generated on the two systems?

Comment: DB are Postgresql for Heroku production and SQLite for local emvironment.

Comment: That's the first thing I'd change then. You're not properly testing your code before deploying to production is you're not using the same RDBMS.

Comment: Are we able to change Heroku's DB to other than Postgres?  Even if we could it probable would be costly( i mean by time to do it )

Comment: OK, I can change local DB to Postgres.